# SQL count number of users hava a value > 1

Tags: sql, select

I need a select which brings two lines, one with the number of people with the " number of hits " > 0 and the other line with the number of people with the " number of hits " = 0

```
SELECT u.name as 'Usuário',u.full_name as 'Nome do Usuário',count(l.referer) as 'Número de Acessos'
FROM   mmp_user u
       LEFT JOIN MMP_MMPUBLISH_LOG l
         on u.id=l.user_id
            AND l.event_date between '2015-08-01' and '2015-08-08'
group by u.name,u.full_name
order by count(l.referer) desc
```

I have,
151 Users
9   accessed and
142 not accessed.

But i don't return this values in select, help me please.

**Table mmp_user fields** (`ID`,`CREATED_BY`,`AVATAR_ID`,`CREATION_DATE`,`EMAIL`,`FULL_NAME`,`LAST_EDITED_BY`,`LAST_EDITION_DATE`,`NAME`,`OBSERVATION`,`USER_PASSWORD`,`PASSWORD_REMINDER`,`SIGNATURE`,`STATUS`,`ADMINISTRATOR`,`DESIGNER`,`SECURITY_OFFICE`,`PUBLISHER`,`BRANCH_ID`,`DEPARTMENT_ID`,`EXTENSION`,`PHONE`,`COMPANY_ID`,`POSITION`,`ADMISSION_DATE`,`PASSWORD_LAST_EDITION_DATE`,`DISMISSED_DATE`,`NEWSLETTER`,`EXPIRE_DATE`,`COMPANY`,`BRANCH`,`DEPARTMENT`,`AREA_ID`,`SITE`,`USER_NUMBER`,`PREFIX_HOME_PHONE`,`PREFIX_MOBILE_PHONE`,`ADDRESS`,`ADDRESS_COMPLEMENT`,`ADDRESS_TYPE`,`CITY`,`NEIGHBORHOOD`,`STATE`,`ZIP_CODE`,`BIRTHDATE`,`GENDER`,`HOME_PHONE`,`MOBILE_PHONE`,`CPF`,`MARIAGE_STATUS`,`NATIONALITY`,`RG`,`EDUCATION`,`URL_SITE`,`FIRST_NAME`,`LAST_NAME`,`ID_SAP`,`PASSWORD_GAFISA`,`NICKNAME`,`CODE_POSITION`,`CREATION_USER_ORIGIN`,`LEVEL_POSITION`,`BIRTH_DATE_VISIBILITY`,`HOME_PHONE_COUNTRY_PREFIX`,`HOME_PHONE_VISIBILITY`,`MOBILE_PHONE_COUNTRY_PREFIX`,`MOBILE_PHONE_VISIBILITY`,`AREA_PREFIX`,`COUNTRY_PREFIX`,`PHONE_OBSERVATION`,`RESPONSIBLE`,`RESOURCE_ID`,`AVATAR_RF_ID`,`RESOURCE_AVATAR_ID`,`AVATAR_URL_LUCENE`,`avatarurl`,`PASSWORD_EXCHANGE`,`USER_NAME_EXCHANGE`,`DOMAIN_EXCHANGE`,`I18N`,`LAST_IMPORT_FILE`,`HIERARCHY_POSITION`,`SECRET_NICKNAME`,`PROFILE_TYPE`,`NOT_VIEW_USER`,`CHANGE_POSITION_DATE`,`DISTINGUISHED_NAME`,`OU_USER`,`AUTH_TOKEN`,`AUTH_TOKEN_EXPIRATION`)

**TableMMP_MMPUBLISH_LOG fields** (`ID`,`MMPUBLISH_LOG_TYPE`,`EVENT_DATE`,`USER_ID`,`TRANSACTION_NAME`,`USER_IP`,`USER_LOGIN`,`USER_NAME`,`SESSION_ID`,`REFERER`,`PUBLISHING_OBJECT_ID`,`PUBLISHING_OBJECT_NAME`,`PHASE_ID`,`PHASE_NAME`,`PHASE_COMMENT`,`ACCESS_URL`,`HOME_PAGE_ID`,`HOMEPAGE_ID`,`phaseComment`,`phaseId`,`phaseName`,`PO_VERSION_NUMBER`)

Thanks

Comment: Could you please update your question with structure of tables and dummy data, and expected results?

Comment: you should also explain how you identify `hits`?

Comment: Are you maybe looking for a  `count(distinct l.referer) `?  Or are you just wanting a  `having count(l.referer) > 1 `?  Just guesses based on what you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap this query with another query and apply a `case` expression to the count:

```
SELECT   access_code, COUNT(*)
FROM     (SELECT     u.name, 
                     u.full_name,
                     CASE WHEN COUNT(l.referer) > 0 THEN 'access'
                          ELSE 'no access'
                     END as access_code 
           FROM      mmp_user u
           LEFT JOIN mmp_mmpupluish_log l ON 
                     u.id=l.user_id AND  
                     l.event_date BETWEEN '2015-08-01' AND '2015-08-08'
           GROUP BY u.name, u.full_name) t
GROUP BY access_code
ORDER BY access_code ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.name Usuário, u.full_name [Nome do Usuário],
     count(l.referer) [Número de Acessos],
     Sum(case when NumberOfHits = 0 then 1 else 0 end) ZeroHitsCount,
     Sum(case when NumberOfHits > 0 then 1 else 0 end) HasSomeHitsCount
FROM   mmp_user u
   LEFT JOIN MMP_MMPUBLISH_LOG l
     on u.id=l.user_id
        AND l.event_date between '2015-08-01' and '2015-08-08'
group by u.name, u.full_name
order by count(l.referer) desc
```

Comment: NumberOfHits = count(l.referer) but i use your select and have and mysql return invalid use of group function

Answer (score 0):

Use a `case` statement:

```
SELECT (case when l.referer is null then 'Not Accessed'
             else 'Accessed'
        end) as which,
       count(*) as 'Número de Acessos'
FROM mmp_user u LEFT JOIN
     MMP_MMPUBLISH_LOG l
     on u.id = l.user_id AND
        l.event_date between '2015-08-01' and '2015-08-08'
group by (case when l.referer is null then 'Not Accessed'
               else 'Accessed'
          end)
order by count(l.referer) desc;
```

Actually, the above counts the number of accesses.  One way to get the number of users is to use `count(distinct u.id)`.  Another way uses a subquery:

```
select AccessType, count(*)
from (select u.*,
             (case when exists (select 1
                                from MMP_MMPUBLISH_LOG l
                                where u.id = l.user_id AND
                                      l.event_date between '2015-08-01' and '2015-08-08'
                               )
                   then 'Accessed' else 'Not Accessed'
              end) as AccessType 
      from mmp_user u
     ) u
group by AccessType;
```

Comment: Accessed         102
Not Accessed 342

But I have 151 users

Comment: @JhonnyPamponet . . . It that with the second query as well, or `count(distinct)`?